# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array - ERROR

Tags: php, css, arrays, wordpress, plugins

I am having trouble figuring out this error. Any help would be highly appreciated!

**Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array**

The error is occuring in this block of code which is a php file from a wordpress plugin called easy social share buttons.

```
// get post types
$pts     = get_post_types( array('show_ui' => true, '_builtin' => true)  );
$cpts    = get_post_types( array('show_ui' => true, '_builtin' => false) );
foreach ( $pts as $pt ) {
if (defined('ESSB3_SSO_ACTIVE') && !$turnoff_essb_optimize_box) {
add_meta_box('essb_metabox_sso', __('Easy Social Share Buttons: Social Share Optimization', ESSB3_TEXT_DOMAIN), 'essb_register_settings_metabox_optimization', $pt, 'normal', 'high');              
}
if (in_array($pt, $display_in_types)) {
add_meta_box('essb_metabox', __('Easy Social Share Buttons',             ESSB3_TEXT_DOMAIN), 'essb_register_settings_metabox_onoff', $pt, 'side', 'high');          
if (!$turnoff_essb_optimize_box) { add_meta_box('essb_metabox_share',  __('Easy Social Share Buttons: Share Customization', ESSB3_TEXT_DOMAIN),  'essb_register_settings_metabox_customization', $pt, 'normal', 'high');
}           
if (!$turnoff_essb_advanced_box) { add_meta_box('essb_metabox_visual', __('Easy Social Share Buttons: Visual Customization', ESSB3_TEXT_DOMAIN), 'essb_register_settings_metabox_visual', $pt, 'normal', 'high');
}           
if (!$turnoff_essb_stats_box) {
add_meta_box('essb_metabox_stats', __('Easy Social Share Buttons: Stats', ESSB3_TEXT_DOMAIN), 'essb_register_settings_metabox_stats', $pt, 'normal', 'core');
}
}               
}
```

**The error occured after I added some custom CSS to the plugin. Here is the css.**

```
div.essb-profiles.essb-profiles-edge.essb-profiles-size-large {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
margin: 20px 0px;
padding: 6px 0px 1px 10px;
}
```

The css and plugin still work the way I intended them too but I receive the error in the admin panel of wordpress on the top of post pages. it is not seen on the front-end of the sight at all but it is unsightly to look at in the admin panel and probably effects the functioning of the code.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: where is this ? $display_in_types

Comment: The error is fairly clear, the function `in_array` expects the second parameter to be an array, that means your second parameter is not an array.

Comment: the $display_in_types is set in this line        $display_in_types = ESSBOptionValuesHelper::options_value($essb_options, 'display_in_types');

Comment: @acro is it an array?

Comment: I guess not, originally I didn't receive the error before I added the CSS but maybe it needs to be an array now. Would this fix it possibly? $display_in_types  = get_post_types( array('show_ui' => true, '_builtin' => true) );

Comment: @acro the function will work if `$display_in_types` is an array.

Comment: Thank you for your help Script47. I solved the problem by changing this if (in_array($pt, $display_in_types)) {       to this        if (!empty($display_in_types) && in_array($pt, $display_in_types)) {      Not sure if this was the best way to do it but it works. Your advice helped, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing this:

```
if (in_array($pt, $display_in_types)); {
  // ...
}
```

to this

```
if (!empty($display_in_types) && in_array($pt, $display_in_types)); {
  // ...
}
```